# Как реализовать несколько Twitter like кнопок на странице?

Tags: php, twitter

Привет. Пытаюсь вывести через php несколько кнопок твиттера.
Скрипт бросил в вывод хедера.
В статьях вывожу кнопки:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share"
   class="twitter-share-button"
   data-url="http://мойсайт/#newstwiter%s">Tweet</a>
```

Здесь айди блоков `newstwiter%s` динамически меняются вместе с url кнопок.

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: при твите на новости, скажем 42, где ее айди `newstwiter42` и url в кнопке твиттера `http://мойсайт/#newstwiter42` - твиттер выдает диалог о публикации новости с url `http://мойсайт/#newstwiter42`. После нажатия на "Твитнуть" счетчики кнопок инкрементируются на всех новостях.

Подскажите в чем подвох?

Заодно и о гугл+ расскажите, если знаете, как там реализовать подобный функционал.